# Visual Studio Code - Python - unhashable type: list

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the mode of a list in python through visual studio code.

I have tried every possible way to do it but regardless of what I do, I get the same error: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

```
filename = "YYY.mat"
filename= r"{}".format(filename)
table = loadmat(filename)
con_list = [[element for element in upperElement] for upperElement in table['Y']]
bv = list(zip(con_list))


bv_stat = [0, min(bv), max(bv), numpy.mean(bv),statistics.mode(bv), np.quantile(bv, .025), np.quantile(bv, .25), np.quantile(bv, .50), np.quantile(bv, .75), np.quantile(bv, .975)]
```

I have tried to turn it into a set or a tuple, but no luck!
I have tried to run a function which goes through it and counts and returns the max value of the count, no luck!

anyone has any idea how I can fix this?!

Comment: share `loadmat` please

Comment: Are you sure that *bv* contains what you hoped for? Try printing it. You may find the result illuminating

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.