# Visual Studio Code - Python - unhashable type: list [codes and error included]

Tags: python

In order to calculate the mode of a list of numbers in Python through Visual Studio Code, I have tried almost every possible way have been mentioned in Internet, but every time I get the same error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Omid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Omid\Desktop\Masterarbeit\Forum copy.py", line 651, in pivot
    bbbb = statistics.mode(bbb)
  File "C:\Users\Omid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\statistics.py", line 557, in mode
    pairs = Counter(iter(data)).most_common(1)
  File "C:\Users\Omid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 593, in __init__
    self.update(iterable, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Omid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 679, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
"


filename = "Demand (MWh)/WB_" + combo_jahr.get() + ".mat"
filename = r"{}".format(filename)
demand_table = loadmat(filename)
con_list = [[element for element in upperElement] for upperElement in demand_table['WB']]
bv = list(zip(con_list))
bbb = tuple(bv)
bbbb = statistics.mode(bbb)
```

Turning it to Tuple or a set, run a function going through it and count it, none of them does the job. These methods work on a simple database in Jupyter Notebooks on my laptop, so the problem does not rely on the installed python or the operational side.
the entire code includes many many different functions such as "mean" and "quantile" which work perfectly on the same list namely "bv". the only one which does not work is "mode".

has anyone any idea how to solve this?!

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with Visual Studio Code. It is a Python question.

Comment: And please make an effort to name your variables somethings useful. `bv`, `bbb`, and `bbbb` are terrible variable names. It makes your code hard to read.

Comment: We don't have access to the MATLAB file (?) you are trying to read so this is hard to reproduce. And what is `loadmat`? Presumably you're using some third-party module here? Please give us a [mre]. What does `demand_table` contain after calling `loadmat(filename)`?

Comment: why ask the same question a few hours later

Comment: [Please don't repost questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/248627). This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69576136/354577

Answer (score 0):

You first need to understand each step of your algorithm.

Let's assume `con_list` is equal to `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`.

```py
bv = list(zip(con_list))
# bv == [([1, 2, 3],), ([4, 5, 6],)]

bbb = tuple(bv)
# bbb == (([1, 2, 3],), ([4, 5, 6],))

bbbb = statistics.mode(bbb)
```

In the last line, Python will try to calculate the mode of a 1-element tuple containing two 1-element tuples containing two 3-element lists, and this is non-sense. It'll raise

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

- If you want to calculate the mode of the whole `con_list` matrix, just do

```
statistics.mode(value for row in con_list for value in row)
# Evaluates to 1
```

The expression inside `statistics.mode(...)` is called a generator comprehension, and it's equivalent to

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

i.e. it flattens all elements of the matrix to a single list.

- If you want to calculate the mode of each row from `con_list`, just do

```
[statistics.mode(row) for row in con_list]
# Evaluates to [1, 4]
```

This is equivalent to

```
[statistics.mode([1, 2, 3]), statistics.mode([4, 5, 6])]
```